# I am not able to login

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

When i enter my password an alert appears on screen saying

Your Session lasted only 10 seconds .......

When i click the checbox saying
view details(~/.xsession-errors file)

it shows

Initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
/etc/mdm/Xsession: Beggining session setup...
localuser:xxxxx being added to access control list

I have already searched on google, reinstalled mdm, reinstalled libcjs0f nothing seems to be working
Pls help

Comment: can downvoters please tell me where can i post these kind of questions

Comment: perhaps the super user stack exchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sudo apt-get remove virtualbox*

Comment: I also suffered

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem and for me the fix was with this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox*
```

I also tried remove but didn't work.

I use Mint 18 Sarah Cinnamon 64, Lenovo B50